# Modify java blob data and stream it

Tags: java, stream, blob

Until now I passed unmodified blob data as an `InputStream`:

```
public InputStream getData(Blob blob) {
  return blob.getData().getBinaryStream();
}
```

Now I want to pass a modified stream with following characteristics:

1. Add additional content from iterators before and after the blob data
2. The blob data contains line breaks (CRLF). I want to add content before and after each line.

We are forced to use Java 7 in our project. Can anyone tell me what is the easiest and most performant way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter (search and replace) array of bytes in an InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743534/filter-search-and-replace-array-of-bytes-in-an-inputstream)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've read it and i'm not quite sure whether i should use `FilterInputStream` or a `BufferedReader`. The blob can be big.