# How to enable non-IANA encodings when using javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader

Tags: java, xml-parsing, stax

I'm using `javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader` to parse XML documents. Unfortunately, some of the documents I'm parsing use non-IANA encoding names, like "macroman" and "ms-ansi". For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="macroman"?>
<foo />
```

This causes the parse to blow up with an exception:

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,42]
Message: Invalid encoding name "macroman".
```

Is there any way to provide a custom encoding handler to my `XMLStreamReader` so that I can augment it with support for the encodings I need??

Comment: I'm assuming you don't have the ability to alter the stream so that it doesn't contain the encoding line? XMLStreamReader has its limitations, and this is one of them.

Comment: Its unfortunate, but you may better be served by choosing a different XML library.

Comment: @Dylan I'm not producing these documents, just consuming them, so I have no control over the encoding line unfortunately. Are there other XML libraries that are more flexible?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the input stream with a transformer that replaces the non-standard charset with the equivalent charset that `XMLStreamReader` does understand.

See [Filter (search and replace) array of bytes in an InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743534/filter-search-and-replace-array-of-bytes-in-an-inputstream)