# How to replace two or more placeholders in-place using FilterInputStream?

Tags: java, file-io, io, inputstream, nio

I have some XML file with placeholders which I need to find and replaces with values. However, I don't want to create temporary files. What I need is described here:

[Filter (search and replace) array of bytes in an InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743534/filter-search-and-replace-array-of-bytes-in-an-inputstream/11158499)

In short, I want to use [FilterInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) and replace placeholders on the fly.

With your permission, I'll place the code here for more clarity:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class ReplacingInputStream extends FilterInputStream {

    LinkedList<Integer> inQueue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    LinkedList<Integer> outQueue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    final byte[] search, replacement;

    protected ReplacingInputStream(InputStream in,
                                   byte[] search,
                                   byte[] replacement) {
        super(in);
        this.search = search;
        this.replacement = replacement;
    }

    private boolean isMatchFound() {
        Iterator<Integer> inIter = inQueue.iterator();
        for (int i = 0; i < search.length; i++)
            if (!inIter.hasNext() || search[i] != inIter.next())
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    private void readAhead() throws IOException {
        // Work up some look-ahead.
        while (inQueue.size() < search.length) {
            int next = super.read();
            inQueue.offer(next);
            if (next == -1)
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {    
        // Next byte already determined.
        if (outQueue.isEmpty()) {
            readAhead();

            if (isMatchFound()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < search.length; i++)
                    inQueue.remove();

                for (byte b : replacement)
                    outQueue.offer((int) b);
            } else
                outQueue.add(inQueue.remove());
        }

        return outQueue.remove();
    }

    // TODO: Override the other read methods.
}
```

This works perfectly for one placeholder, but what if I need to replace two? And in my case, the placeholders have different lengths. For example:

```
byte[] firstPlaceholder = "abc".getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] secondPlaceholder = "replace_this".getBytes("UTF-8");
```

And the string that contains the placeholders:

```
"Hello abc world, I want to replace_this line here"
```

Comment: simple solution: `FilterInputStream` is a `InputStream` it can be chained, that is, `new ReplacingInputStream(new ReplacingInputStream(inputStream, search1, repl`), search2, repl2)` (probably not suitable for many substitutions) - otherwise coding will be too complex for comment

Comment: Hmm .. good idea, thank you.

Comment: @user15244370 - Looks like that's what I need. I checked, it works well. If you write an answer, I will accept it.